# Difference in stats on the same domain - seo related

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 301-redirect

Recently i started to optimize my company's website. With a little help of market samurai.

One of the adjustments was a www redirect to the prefered domain. We currently
rank on #8 for our desired keyword with the domain without the www. If I add a custom url (our domain with www), we see a difference in stats BLP (backlinks to the page) {it's the website on top}

Can anyone tell me how i could merge this so we might even rank better for our keyword?

### What I did so far:

3 weeks ago set the www.duo.be as prefered domain in GWT and put a 301 redirect in place so the duo.be gets redirected to www.duo.be
Both domains are in GWT and both with www.duo.be as preferred domain.

Tho I see no change.

Can anyone help me out, because i'm clueless.

Marketsamurai screenshot: [image: table of stats]https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYkb8.png

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Market Samurai, but I did find out that BLP is backlinks to the page. If people have been linking to duo.be then that's diluting yours stats. However apart from contacting everyone and asking them to change their links to www.duo.be there's not a lot you can do.

If you've changed your preferred domain then it's going to take a while for search engines to recrawl the pages on that domain.

DMOZ will only list one entry for your site so as duo.be and www.duo.be are effectively the same site, one's going to be in DMOZ and one isn't.

Comment: My biggest concern is the IC (indexed content) and DMZ (Dmoz Directory). I have no idea why the indexed page differ so much.. In the past we had www.duo.be as prefered domain, but then the management went for duo.be because it was estetically better. The DMZ listening is important for our Domain authority

Comment: I've updated my answer to respond to that.

Comment: Then it's just a matter of time that Google will rank the prefered www.duo.be instead of the current one duo.be?

Because of you look to one of our main keywords 'webdesign Brugge' we are ranking in 7th pos. for Google Belgium with a domain that has stats which are less good...